# Cant login to my main account after System Update

Tags: greeter, updates, desktop, language

I after a system update when i restarted my computer cant login in my main account. After i type the password screen goes black and throw me again at login screen. I can login with as guest.

I loged in with cairo-dock but many things are missing and i noticed that there is only the Greek language installed. I cant change to english or add it.

Anyone knows what is going on ?

Comment: please try my answer and let me know ,the result =)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the pantheon-desktop.

i reinstalled it and now everything works fine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

Comment: If it is problem with desktop , how you login as guest ? :\

Comment: Good point -.- but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way to solve the problem .

1.Open tty by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

2 . Login

3 . `cd ~`

4 . `sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak`

5 .  `sudo service lightdm restart`

6 .  `sudo reboot`

Comment: I used ctrl + alt + f1 . i logged in . if i `cd ~` there isnt any `.Xauthority` file.
`.Xauthority` is inside `/home/sin` . i renamed it to `.XauthorityBak` but isnt working

Comment: Please don't change any file names...`cd ~` means `cd /home/user_name`

Comment: use `ls -a` to see the file names and run `sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak` then `sudo reboot`

Comment: mv command renames. i allready done what you told me but nothing happened.

Comment: please see edited answer and let me know the result ,=)

Comment: I used lightdm restart also :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30528/discussion-between-ravan-and-isengart).