# Can't login, in a Login loop

Tags: greeter, release-juno

I get the normal elementary OS greeter, I login (it doesn't give a password error) but then I'm returned to the greeter again.
This also happened to me earlier this month, then I ended up reinstalling.

I know there are a lot of existing similar questions, but I've gone through them (listed below) and the solutions don't seem to help.

- [can't log back in to Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki 64bit](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/12758)
- [I can't login , return to login screen (it isn't Xauthority)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/2568)
- [Can't login after upgrade](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/2443)
- [I get logged out as soon as I log in](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/7279)
- [Cant login to my main account after System Update](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/2630)
- [Login redirects back to login screen](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/7947) (I get not setup properly when I try this)
- [Can't start GUI in Elementary OS Loki 0.4.1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/15197)
- [New install has a login loop](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/3042)

Some info:

- I'm running Juno
- I'm on a XPS 9550
- It has a Nvidia card but I haven't installed the Nvidia drivers
- I've removed those .Xauthority and .ICEauthority
- I've restarted lightdm
- No custom kernel
- No elementary tweaks
- My HD's and partitions aren't full
- I've reinstalled `elementary-desktop` and `pantheon-greeter`
- I've added a new user ([instructions](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/07/how-to-create-new-user-account-from.html)) but I get the same behaivior when attempting to login to that user.

`/var/log/lightdm` from when I attempt to login:

```
[+3092.74s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+3092.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=3922: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+3092.79s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user peteruithoven: Success
[+3092.79s] DEBUG: User peteruithoven authorized
[+3093.43s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session pantheon
[+3093.43s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
[+3093.43s] DEBUG: Terminating login1 session c3
[+3093.44s] DEBUG: Session pid=1931: Sending SIGTERM
[+3093.45s] DEBUG: Session pid=1931: Exited with return value 0
[+3093.45s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+3093.45s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Greeter stopped, running session
[+3093.45s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
[+3093.45s] DEBUG: Session pid=3922: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=pantheon
[+3093.45s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/peteruithoven
[+3093.45s] DEBUG: Session pid=3922: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+3093.51s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+3093.51s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c4
[+3093.51s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c4
[+3093.51s] DEBUG: Session c4 is already active
[+3096.26s] DEBUG: Session pid=3922: Exited with return value 1
[+3096.26s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+3096.26s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+3096.26s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 1926
[+3098.10s] DEBUG: Process 1926 exited with return value 0
[+3098.10s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+3098.10s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Active display server stopped, starting greeter
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Launching X Server
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: Launching process 4251: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+3098.11s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+3099.09s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 4251
[+3099.09s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Got signal from X server :0
[+3099.09s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+3099.14s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+3099.14s] DEBUG: Session pid=4256: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+3099.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=4256: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+3099.18s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+3099.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=4256: Running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/io.elementary.greeter
[+3099.18s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm
[+3099.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=4256: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log
[+3099.35s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+3099.35s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c5
[+3099.35s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c5
[+3099.35s] DEBUG: Session c5 is already active
[+3099.68s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.26.0 api=1 resettable=false
[+3100.34s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for peteruithoven
[+3100.34s] DEBUG: Session pid=4360: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'peteruithoven'
[+3100.36s] DEBUG: Session pid=4360: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+3100.36s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
```

Logs from ´journalctl´ when I tried to login:

```
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: session-c5.scope: Killing process 4256 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: session-c5.scope: Killing process 4276 (lightdm-greeter) with signal SIGTERM.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: session-c5.scope: Killing process 4277 (io.elementary.g) with signal SIGTERM.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: session-c5.scope: Killing process 4282 (io.elementary.g) with signal SIGTERM.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: session-c5.scope: Killing process 4316 (wingpanel) with signal SIGTERM.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: session-c5.scope: Killing process 4341 (gsd-a11y-settin) with signal SIGTERM.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: session-c5.scope: Killing process 4343 (gsd-color) with signal SIGTERM.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: session-c5.scope: Killing process 4347 (gsd-power) with signal SIGTERM.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: session-c5.scope: Killing process 4349 (gsd-xsettings) with signal SIGTERM.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: Stopping Session c5 of user lightdm.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps lightdm[4256]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
dec 18 15:27:01 xps lightdm[4360]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user peteruithoven by (uid=0)
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd-logind[897]: New session c6 of user peteruithoven.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: Started Session c6 of user peteruithoven.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: Stopped Session c5 of user lightdm.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd-logind[897]: Removed session c5.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 110...
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopping sandboxed app permission store...
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopping flatpak document portal service...
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped target Default.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped sandboxed app permission store.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped flatpak document portal service.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped target Basic System.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped target Sockets.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped target Timers.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Stopped target Paths.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Reached target Shutdown.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Starting Exit the Session...
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4259]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 4471 (kill).
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[4260]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user lightdm
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 110.
dec 18 15:27:01 xps systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.
dec 18 15:27:02 xps at-spi-bus-launcher[4057]: dbus-daemon[4062]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1000 pid=4550 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-acceler" label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:02 xps at-spi-bus-launcher[4057]: dbus-daemon[4062]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
dec 18 15:27:02 xps at-spi-bus-launcher[4057]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gnome-session[4439]: gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file custom-command2.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file custom-command2.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gnome-session[4439]: gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file libinput-gestures.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file libinput-gestures.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
dec 18 15:27:02 xps kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
dec 18 15:27:02 xps spice-vdagent[4577]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gnome-session[4439]: gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
dec 18 15:27:02 xps io.elementary.dpms-helper.desktop[4591]: org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power manage-dpms-defaults is false.
dec 18 15:27:02 xps io.elementary.dpms-helper.desktop[4591]: Using settings found in io.elementary.dpms (0 seconds = Never).
dec 18 15:27:02 xps io.elementary.dpms-helper.desktop[4591]:     Standby: 300 seconds
dec 18 15:27:02 xps io.elementary.dpms-helper.desktop[4591]:     Suspend: 0 seconds
dec 18 15:27:02 xps io.elementary.dpms-helper.desktop[4591]:     Off: 0 seconds
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gnome-keyring-pkcs11-pantheon.desktop[4620]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gnome-keyring-ssh-pantheon.desktop[4597]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
dec 18 15:27:02 xps dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.147' (uid=1000 pid=4631 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-rfkill " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:02 xps systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
dec 18 15:27:02 xps dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.148' (uid=1000 pid=4586 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-datetime " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:02 xps systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
dec 18 15:27:02 xps rtkit-daemon[1872]: Successfully made thread 4668 of process 4668 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
dec 18 15:27:02 xps rtkit-daemon[1872]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
dec 18 15:27:02 xps pulseaudio[4668]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
dec 18 15:27:02 xps dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service' requested by ':1.151' (uid=1000 pid=4579 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:02 xps systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gsd-sharing[4589]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gsd-sharing[4589]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit vino-server.service not loaded.
dec 18 15:27:02 xps gsd-xsettings[4616]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
dec 18 15:27:02 xps dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
dec 18 15:27:02 xps systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps rtkit-daemon[1872]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps rtkit-daemon[1872]: Successfully made thread 4692 of process 4668 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps rtkit-daemon[1872]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
dec 18 15:27:03 xps systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps bluetoothd[906]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.157 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
dec 18 15:27:03 xps bluetoothd[906]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.157 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
dec 18 15:27:03 xps pulseaudio[4668]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
dec 18 15:27:03 xps rtkit-daemon[1872]: Successfully made thread 4695 of process 4695 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps rtkit-daemon[1872]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps pulseaudio[4695]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps dbus-daemon[942]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
dec 18 15:27:03 xps systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps gala.desktop[4703]: Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps gala.desktop[4703]: Window manager warning: Trying to re-add keybinding "switch-to-workspace-last".
dec 18 15:27:03 xps gala.desktop[4703]: Window manager warning: Trying to re-add keybinding "move-to-workspace-last".
dec 18 15:27:03 xps gala[4703]: Settings schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings' does not contain a key named 'tile-topleft'
dec 18 15:27:03 xps kernel: traps: gala[4703] trap int3 ip:7f9f8d916e11 sp:7ffed9ccb9f0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.3[7f9f8d8c5000+113000]
dec 18 15:27:03 xps gnome-session[4439]: gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 5
dec 18 15:27:03 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 5
dec 18 15:27:03 xps gsd-power[4626]: Failed to acquire idle monitor object manager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gala.desktop[4716]: Window manager warning: Trying to re-add keybinding "switch-to-workspace-last".
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gala.desktop[4716]: Window manager warning: Trying to re-add keybinding "move-to-workspace-last".
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gala[4716]: Settings schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings' does not contain a key named 'tile-topleft'
dec 18 15:27:04 xps kernel: traps: gala[4716] trap int3 ip:7f5624a5ae11 sp:7ffd47f3fe00 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.3[7f5624a09000+113000]
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gnome-session[4439]: gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 5
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gnome-session[4439]: gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: App 'gala.desktop' respawning too quickly
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 5
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: WARNING: App 'gala.desktop' respawning too quickly
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: Unrecoverable failure in required component gala.desktop
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gnome-session[4439]: gnome-session-binary[4439]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
dec 18 15:27:04 xps kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
dec 18 15:27:04 xps lightdm[4360]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user peteruithoven
dec 18 15:27:04 xps bluetoothd[906]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.157 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
dec 18 15:27:04 xps bluetoothd[906]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.157 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gsd-wacom[4571]: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gsd-color[4565]: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
dec 18 15:27:04 xps at-spi-bus-launcher[4057]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
dec 18 15:27:04 xps at-spi-bus-launcher[4057]:       after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gsd-media-keys[4566]: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gsd-clipboard[4585]: gsd-clipboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gsd-xsettings[4616]: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gsd-power[4626]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gsd-keyboard[4579]: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps lightdm[4731]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dec 18 15:27:07 xps lightdm[4731]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
dec 18 15:27:07 xps lightdm[4731]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dec 18 15:27:07 xps lightdm[4731]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
dec 18 15:27:07 xps lightdm[4731]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of lightdm.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 110...
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd-logind[897]: New session c7 of user lightdm.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[1]: Started Session c7 of user lightdm.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Reached target Timers.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Reached target Paths.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Reached target Sockets.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Reached target Basic System.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Reached target Default.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Startup finished in 89ms.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 110.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-spi-dbus-bus.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=110 pid=4752 comm="/usr/sbin/io.elementary.greeter " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Started Accessibility services bus.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps at-spi-bus-launcher[4761]: dbus-daemon[4769]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=110 pid=4752 comm="/usr/sbin/io.elementary.greeter " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:07 xps at-spi-bus-launcher[4761]: dbus-daemon[4769]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
dec 18 15:27:07 xps at-spi-bus-launcher[4761]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=110 pid=4752 comm="/usr/sbin/io.elementary.greeter " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.1' (uid=110 pid=4752 comm="/usr/sbin/io.elementary.greeter " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop' unit='xdg-desktop-portal.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=110 pid=4791 comm="wingpanel -g " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Starting Portal service...
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Documents' unit='xdg-document-portal.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=110 pid=4796 comm="/usr/lib/xdg-desktop-portal/xdg-desktop-portal " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Starting flatpak document portal service...
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore' unit='xdg-permission-store.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=110 pid=4800 comm="/usr/lib/xdg-desktop-portal/xdg-document-portal " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Starting sandboxed app permission store...
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore'
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Started sandboxed app permission store.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Documents'
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Started flatpak document portal service.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps dbus-daemon[4754]: [session uid=110 pid=4754] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk' unit='xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=110 pid=4796 comm="/usr/lib/xdg-desktop-portal/xdg-desktop-portal " label="unconfined")
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Starting Portal service (GTK+/GNOME implementation)...
dec 18 15:27:07 xps xdg-desktop-portal-gtk[4814]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
dec 18 15:27:07 xps xdg-desktop-por[4814]: cannot open display: 
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Failed to start Portal service (GTK+/GNOME implementation).
dec 18 15:27:08 xps at-spi-bus-laun[4761]: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'RegisterClient'
dec 18 15:27:08 xps lightdm[4826]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dec 18 15:27:08 xps lightdm[4826]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
dec 18 15:27:08 xps lightdm[4826]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dec 18 15:27:08 xps lightdm[4826]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
dec 18 15:27:08 xps lightdm[4826]: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "peteruithoven"
```

The parts that are red:

```
dec 18 15:27:02 xps spice-vdagent[4577]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
dec 18 15:27:03 xps pulseaudio[4668]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
dec 18 15:27:03 xps pulseaudio[4695]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
dec 18 15:27:03 xps gala[4703]: Settings schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings' does not contain a key named 'tile-topleft'
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gala[4716]: Settings schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings' does not contain a key named 'tile-topleft'
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: Unrecoverable failure in required component gala.desktop
dec 18 15:27:04 xps gnome-session-binary[4439]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
dec 18 15:27:07 xps lightdm[4731]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dec 18 15:27:07 xps lightdm[4731]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
dec 18 15:27:07 xps lightdm[4731]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dec 18 15:27:07 xps lightdm[4731]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
dec 18 15:27:07 xps systemd[4734]: Failed to start Portal service (GTK+/GNOME implementation).
dec 18 15:27:08 xps lightdm[4826]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dec 18 15:27:08 xps lightdm[4826]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
dec 18 15:27:08 xps lightdm[4826]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dec 18 15:27:08 xps lightdm[4826]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
dec 18 15:27:32 xps systemd[4734]: Failed to start Portal service.
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution! I was to blame. I noticed the following error from journalctl:

```
dec 18 15:27:03 xps gala[4703]: Settings schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings' does not contain a key named 'tile-topleft'
```

This is a key binding from my [Gala Quarter tiling pull request](https://github.com/elementary/gala/pull/408) that I'm running locally. 
Apparently my quarter tiling plugin was still there (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gala/plugins/), it was triggered, but because it was missing it's settings keys it crashed Gala.

All I had to do was re-compile and install my custom gala version. This works because it reintroduces the settings keys.

Another solution is to remove the specific plugin:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gala/plugins/libgala-quartertiler.so
```